# How dragons deal with lack of fingers

Tags: mythical-creatures, dragons

This was touched on in [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/31688/50404): "dragons as you describe them do not have the appendages necessary for careful, accurate control of their environment".

If there are "classic" dragons (i.e. large and with claws) with human level intelligence, what is a reasonable explanation for the ability to:

(1) Record information.

(2) Shape their environment (e.g. not being restricted to living in caves).

(3) Create / manufacture things in general.

Comment: The "classic" dragons would have used telekinesis.

Comment: unlike T-rex, your dragons probably don't need to count and claps but it may have evolved powerful brains similar to how late professor Stephen Hawking worked out his theories about black holes and the universe(singular as I believed he dislike the idea of multiverse) and then your dragons could have "prehensile" tongue for gripping tools, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the written language of the dragons in the videogame Skyrim? It scratches and dots easily done with claws not requiring much dexterity. Base their written language on what impressions they can leave. (Foot prints, heck even smells or charring patterns on the walls).

Point 2, ever watch a dog reshape their toys, bed etc? A lot can be done with only a jaw though most dragons seem to be able to use their claws/wings whatever at least a little.

Point 3, followers. Guide some more handi-capable species do the work for them. (Slave or willing, either can be interesting in the story).

Answer (score 0):

They breath fire dude, they don't need fingers...

also dragons are widely regarded as extremely magic creatures. In some lore they can cast spells better than any or most human based characters. Also, in some lore they DO have fingers with nice long claws on them. If you're creating a book and need the dragons to have fingers then just put fingers on them. But hey lets answer your questions by the book...

1. Record information:
   let's say the dragons fire breath allows them to engrave their dragon language into stone or other solid objects that are traditionally non-flammable
2. Shape their environment:
   They have claws and can burrow into the ground. Perhaps there's a species of human/dragon hybrids with human like hands and fingers with opposable thumbs (the opposable thumb thing is key brah).
3. Create/manufacture things in general:
   Dragons traditionally steal things...think back to Smaug in the Hobbit. Perhaps they can use magic and their fire to craft metal and produce magic items...

In short use your imagination and have fun. It's your world so craft it into whatever you want.